# Foundation grid center with margin

Tags: css, sass, zurb-foundation

Why does the Foundation grid center itself by default? Is there a utility class I can use to allow the grid row to span full width?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**For Foundation 6:**

Add "expanded" class to .row to remove max-width, like this:

```
<div class="row expanded">
```

**For Foundation 5:**

Add this to your CSS file:

```
.row.expanded {max-width: none; }
.row.expanded .row {margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; }
```

Then you can add the "expanded" class to .row.

Comment: That is available in Foundation version 6 only? I am using version 5x :(